# sgetn "overwrites" a const parameter

Tags: c++, file, buffer

```
std::vector<std::bitset<8>>& vecBin
```

If vecBin has exactly 4 elements, the following situation happens:

```
bool BinFinder::containsInFile(const std::vector<std::bitset<8>>& vecBin, uint fails/* = 1*/)
{
    if (fails >= vecBin.size()) return true;

    file.open(path, std::ifstream::binary);
    if ((file.rdstate() & std::ifstream::failbit ) != 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    // Reading blocks of 4 KiB (MBLOCK_SIZE = 4096 Bytes)
    //file.read(buff, MBLOCK_SIZE);
    bool found {};
    uint bytesRead { 1 }, foundAtJ {}, failed {};
    while(/*file.good()*/!file.eof() && !found && bytesRead > 0)
    {
        failed = 0;

        // Reading blocks until 4 KiB (MBLOCK_SIZE = 4096 Bytes)
        //bytesRead = file.rdbuf()->sgetn(buff, MBLOCK_SIZE);
        std::streambuf *sb = file.rdbuf();  //debug

        std::cout << "After rdbuf" << std::endl;    //debug
        for (auto i = 0; i < vecBin.size(); ++i)    //debug
            std::cout << vecBin.at(i) << std::endl; //debug

        bytesRead = sb->sgetn(buff, MBLOCK_SIZE);   //debug

        std::cout << "After sgetn" << std::endl;    //debug
        for (auto i = 0; i < vecBin.size(); ++i)    //debug
            std::cout << vecBin.at(i) << std::endl; //debug


...
```

After the call to sgetn(buff, MBLOCK_SIZE), is like the this call overwrites the content of vecBin sice the output of this snippet code is:

`output
After rdbuf
01100010
01100011
01110101
10101010
After sgetn
00110011
00001010
01101111
10101010`

Why sgetn is modifying the content of vecBin?!

Answer (score 1):

`sgetn` will get characters from its associated stream buffer and store them in the array you passed it. Since your code does not include any kind of definition of `buff`, assuming that it turns out to be an alias to the contents of `vecBin` explains why `vecBin` gets changed...